# StaleElementReferenceError in ruby selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, staleobjectstateexception

I was trying to automate rediff.com . I went from one page to other but when i came back i got staleException . I tried a lot but couldn't fix it.
I am attaching the code snippet too. Any help would be appreciated.

@driver.get "http://shopping.rediff.com/?sc_cid=inhome_icon"

@driver.manage.window.maximize

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds

begin

```
element = wait.until { @driver.find_element(:xpath,".//*[@id='popular_cat']") }
```

ensure

```
box=@driver.find_element(:xpath,".//*[@id='popular_cat']")
```

end
  links=box.find_elements(:tag_name,"a")

puts "Total links are:#{links.size}"

links.each do |i|

```
  puts "--------------------"
  puts "Value of all links is:#{i.text}"
  i.click
  puts "Title of page is :#{@driver.title}"
  @driver.get "http://shopping.rediff.com/?sc_cid=inhome_icon"
  box=@driver.find_element(:xpath,".//*[@id='popular_cat']")
  links=box.find_elements(:tag_name,"a")

end
```

Comment: I suspect your using Firefox?  If so, that would explain the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you reload the page (because you are going to other page and then going back or because you simple reloaded the page) your references to the links 'links=box.find_elements(:tag_name,"a")' are lost.

I would suggest a few changes in order to workaround this (might not be the best solution)

`links = box.find_elements(:tag_name,"a").size
    links_counter = 0
    while links_counter < links
        box = @driver.find_element(:xpath,".//*[@id='popular_cat']")
        current_link = box.find_elements(:tag_name,"a")[links_counter]
        links_counter += 1
        puts "--------------------"
        puts "Value of all links is:#{current_link.text}"
        current_link.click
        puts "Title of page is :#{@driver.title}"
        @driver.get "http://shopping.rediff.com/?sc_cid=inhome_icon"
    end`

I hope this helps you!

Best,
Fernando

Comment: Thanks for swift reply..
You made my day and +1 for help..
Could you please share any link from where i can learn ruby?

Comment: Sure, you can go to codecademy site or codeschool, they have good tutorials and lessons. Also [link] (http://railscasts.com/) for more ruby on rails things (prety cool tutos).

Sorry about the delay :D